# htaccess 301 Redirect with querystring

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

In my htaccess I want to do 301 redirects from all of the products that use the standarddetail page

https://www.domain.com/standarddetail.asp​?cid=4135

To the following page:
https://www.domain.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=4135

I want to do this for all (cid) query strings

I have a couple of thousand products that appear on this standarddetail.asp page using the querystring (cid) and I want them to go to the new page using the product_id= querystring.

I want them to be 301 redirects.

How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root, add this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cid=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^standarddetail\.asp$ index.php?route=product/product&product_id=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This did not work. At one point, I tried to do a one to one redirect and even that did not work. There must be some sort of conflict here. Below is what failed before. 

Redirect 301 /standarddetail.asp​?cid=4135 https://www.domain.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=4135

Comment: Jon Lin, do you have anything suggestions?

Comment: @LeeFairbanks sorry, forgot you cant match against the query string in the `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch`. You need to use mod_rewrite

Comment: What should the redirect be then?

Comment: The one above did not work.
@Jon Lin
`code`
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cid=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^standarddetail\.asp$ index.php?route=product/product&product_id=%1 [L,R=301]
`code`

Comment: I noticed that the above is adding the directory path in front which is causing the new url to fail.

Comment: This slight variation on yours seemed to do the trick. I was also having some caching issues and closing everything down after changing things helped. Thanks Jon Lin for your help and for sticking with it. 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cid=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^cat_science\.asp$ https://www.domain.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=%1 [L,R=301]